# Can i Extract the Phone Numbers from Text using C#.net?

Tags: c#

Can i Extract all the Phone Numbers from Text using C#.net?

Comment: can u be specific ? which text..give us any example.

Comment: In which country? which format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regular Expressions should allow you to do this.

There are a few phone number examples given in https://web.archive.org/web/20120527171308/http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Regular_Expression_Recipes%E2%80%94Using_Common_Patterns

To use a regular expression on some text, you can use:

```
var exp = new Regex(
    @"(\(?[0-9]{3}\)?)?\-?[0-9]{3}\-?[0-9]{4}", // North American example
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var text = "My text including phone numbers";
MatchCollection matchList = exp.Matches(text);

// now iterate over matchList.Matches
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression look at this site [regex library](http://regexlib.com/)

Answer (score 1):

• Match a North American phone number with an optional area code and an optional - character to be used in the phone number and no extension:

```
^(\(?[0-9]{3}\)?)?\-?[0-9]{3}\-?[0-9]{4}$
```

• Match a phone number like before but allow an optional five-digit extension prefixed with either ext or extension:

```
^(\(?[0-9]{3}\)?)?\-?[0-9]{3}\-?[0-9]{4}(\s*ext(ension)?[0-9]{5})?$
```